# FreeBSD compilation on Pandaboard

Tags: kernel, freebsd

I have a pandaboard and want to compile freebsd kernel. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.I have cloned the freebsd source and crochet which supports various boards, but there is no elaborate steps that I could find to compile the freebsd source for Pandaboard. Is there any tutorial or something for FreeBSD. Like for linux, I can easily find many tuts for building kernel from linux kernel source.

And what kind of distribution(e.g., Ubuntu for Linux) does FreeBSD use so that I can bring up FreeBSD on pandaboard with complete BSD distribution.

Answer (score 0):

It will be faster if you compile and create your own images on another system with more hardware capabilities and later just copy the images over your [pandaboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PandaBoard),  for doing this, you could check [fabrik.red](https://fabrik.red/) and also use the scripts used to create the images, for example, https://github.com/fabrik-red/images

But to know better the internals the [FreeBSD Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/kernelconfig-building.html) is the recommended source.

For custom releases you could also check `/usr/src/release`: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/releng/release-build.html